# Ashx route not working - Piranha CMS - Failed to load resource

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ashx, piranha-cms

I'm facing this issue, but I don't know why. How do I fix this?

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
    http://www.xxx/res.ashx/areas/manager/content/css/style.min.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  
    http://www.xxx/res.ashx/areas/manager/content/js/ext/jquery-1.7.2.min.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
     http://www.xxx/res.ashx/areas/manager/content/js/jquery.manager.js
```

> Installed Piranha:
>   https://github.com/nickvee/Piranha.Bootstrap/tree/master/Piranha.Bootstrap
>   on the server

Original location is: http://www.xxx/content/css/style.min.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repository you've installed hasn't been updated for 7 months and uses a rather old version of Piranha CMS (2.0.3). If you need support for it you'll have to ask the author of the Piranha.Bootstrap repository at GitHub, preferably by adding a new issue [here](https://github.com/nickvee/Piranha.Bootstrap/issues).

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when deploying to a server.
It's because `*.ashx` is not handled by any program.

Try to configure Handler Mapping like this:

[image: handler mappings image]